# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2

Tags: mysql

Im trying to understand how MySql 5.7 works. In query bellow

```
      SELECT 
        r.*,
        CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) AS name
      FROM
        `events` AS r 
        LEFT JOIN `users` AS u 
          ON r.user_id = u.id 
      WHERE r.event_id = 1 
      GROUP BY r.user_id 
      ORDER BY r.date ;
```

I'm getting an error " SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'r.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by [code: 42000] "

But query like this works fine:

```
  SELECT 
        r.id,
        r.event_id,
        r.user_id,
        r.date
        CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) AS name
      FROM
        `events` AS r 
        LEFT JOIN `users` AS u 
          ON r.user_id = u.id 
      WHERE r.event_id = 1 
      GROUP BY r.user_id, r.event_id, r.id, r.date
      ORDER BY r.date ;
```

Since I'm working on localhost, I can make changes to my.ini file and set sql_mode to "STRICT_ALL_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"

but when going live this is going to be a problem, since not to many people will have access to my.ini file especially on shared hosting.

It seems to me bit Non-efficient to declare every single field and aggregate accordingly.

Since my knowledge in MySql is just beginner, is there a better way to write above query. In a case when I need to pull 10 or 20 fields from a single table aggregating all of them seems bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is is simple you must declare  in group by all the columns not involved  in aggregation function

your

```
SELECT 
    r.id,
    r.event_id,
    r.user_id,
    r.date
    CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) AS name
  FROM
    `events` AS r 
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u 
      ON r.user_id = u.id 
  WHERE r.event_id = 1 
  GROUP BY r.user_id, r.event_id, r.id, r.date
  ORDER BY r.date ;
```

is equivalent  to

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    r.id,
    r.event_id,
    r.user_id,
    r.date
    CONCAT(u.fname, ' ', u.lname) AS name
  FROM
    `events` AS r 
    LEFT JOIN `users` AS u 
      ON r.user_id = u.id 
  WHERE r.event_id = 1 
  ORDER BY r.date ;
```

In the first you have r.* but this is not in group by

Comment: Note to OP: An aggregation function in the select clause is like  `count()`, `sum()`, etc... where you're evaluating all values of the grouping.

Comment: correct  concat is not an aggregation function  is linear .. group_concat is an aggregation function

Comment: I have not edit you comment . i have said  that your comment is correct..